# Python break a nested for loop and restart the while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, restart, continue

I created a little `while` loop to check if any of the special chars in the list are in the name of the folder.
I would like to make it stop iterating the `for` loop at the first character detected and restart the `while`

```
folder_set = False
while folder_set == False:
    inacceptable = ['.', ',', '-', '(', ')', '*', '²', '=', '^', '$', ';', 
    ':', '!', '§', '?', '/', '{', '}']
    folder = input('Enter folder here: ').lower()
    for i in inacceptable:
        if i in folder:
            print(f'Your folder name has a special character {i}, please make 
            sure the folder name does not contain any special character:\n {" 
            ".join(inacceptable)}, or any other special character.')
            folder_set == False
            breakloop = 'continue'
            continue
    folder_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), str(folder))
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path) == True:
        confirmation = input('Folder already exists, would you like to save 
        your files in it? (yes/no) ', )
    if confirmation.lower() == 'yes':
        folder_set = True
    else:
        folder_set = True
```

But it does not work. Can you explain why?
Also, if I try to print the `breakloop` variable, I receive an error `breakloop not defined`

Comment: You would need to set ```folder_set``` to true inorder to break the while loop if the condition is satisfied & there is also a typo in there.

Comment: I am looking to break the `for` loop not the while

Comment: You do not need the for loop at all. Use set intersection: `bad=set(inacceptible) & set(folder); if bad: folder_set=True; print(bad)` (note that there is _one_ `=` in an assignment).

Comment: use `break` instead of `continue` to break the loop. If `breakloop` is not defined it means one of the for didn't have anything to iterate, the if was never true, you are trying to use `breakloop` outside of its scope.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is an error in how you've pasted your code or if it was there originally too. But, your code after the while loop is not indented. Ok, so you fixed that in your edit.

You don't need to continue in the for loop but instead break over there and remove the line `folder_set == False`

Then, add a variable `breakloop` defined after the start of the while loop set to True. It must be set to False in the for loop instead of folder_set. After the for loop, check for breakloop and break. Final code:

```
unacceptable = ['.', ',', '-', '(', ')', '*', '²', '=', '^', '$', ';', ':', '!', '§', '?', '/', '{', '}']

while True:
    breakloop = True
    folder = input('Enter folder here: ').lower()

    for i in unacceptable:
        if i in folder:
            print("Your folder name has a special character " + i + ", please make sure the folder name does not contain any special characters from:\n " + ' '.join(unacceptable) + ", or any other.")
            breakloop = False
            break

    if breakloop:
        break
```

**EDIT:** I edited your print statement and moved *un*acceptable outside the while loop it doesn't have to be redefined for each iteration.

Comment: @MehdiRezzagHebla please upvote and mark the answer as accepted if it fixed your problem (click the tick). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really into Python but i suggest you to make **folder_set = true** or delete it because you set it to false and if **while is false** it means it will never get into it to iterate, something else i suggest is :

```
inacceptable = ['.', ',', '-', '(', ')', '*', '²', '=', '^', '$', ';', ':', '!', '§', '?', '/', '{', '}']
folder = input('Enter folder here: ').lower()
for i in inacceptable:
    if i in folder:
        print(f'Your folder name has a special character {i}, please make sure the folder name does not contain any special character:\n {" ".join(inacceptable)}, or any other special character.')
        break
```

I hope this helps you !